# How to make a time like donut chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I’ve started learning Python not that long ago and am trying to make

[image: this graph]

I wanted to separate the slices by thirty minutes (like a clock) and add their portrait in the middle, but I really don't know what I’m doing here.

Here’s what I have so far:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Activity=['Sleep', 'Dressing', 'Compose', 'Lessons', 'Lunch and social', 
          'Compose or concerts', 'Courting Constanze', 'Compose']
slices=[150, 30, 60, 120, 120, 120, 60, 60]
Colors=['White', '#f8b863', '#6fae72', '#46b5d1', '#f8b863', '#939598', 
        '#f8b863', '#6fae72'] 

plt.pie(slices, labels=Activity, colors=Colors, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'gray'}, 
        counterclock=False, startangle=75) 

centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle) 

plt.title('"Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart"')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What specifically is your question? It looks like you are on the right track. Are you wondering how to add the portrait to the middle of the image?